# Is there a way to remove explicit attribute names in parsing XML data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my XML parsing query, I have:

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperId, PublisherId,
Data.value('(/Game/DeveloperName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') DeveloperName,
Data.value('(/Game/PublisherName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') PublisherName,
Data.value('(/Game/Genre/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') Genre,
FROM GameDataTable;
```

I was wondering if it is possible to not explicitly write

```
'DeveloperName, Publisher, Genre'
```

to possibly make human error in typos less prevalent and reduce some space. I thought about creating a temporary table but is that not efficient?

If anyone had any tips, that'd be great.

Comment: Assuming you mean the XQuery and not the alias'.... short answer no, pretty sure you can't reference elements by index, since, by design they needn't necessarily be in the same order on two different records.  But, since you appear to have foreign keys for publisher/developer -- why do you have that same data in the XML anyway?  Can you not join the reference tables and grab the name value from the developer/publisher tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to normalize your data and then pivot (the pivot is optional)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,DeveloperID int,PublisherID int,Data xml)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,2365,10056,'<Game><DeveloperName>This is the Developer Name</DeveloperName><PublisherName>This is the Publisher Name</PublisherName><Genre>Drama</Genre></Game>')

Select *
 From (
        Select A.ID
              ,A.DeveloperID
              ,A.PublisherID
              ,B.*
         From  @YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                        Select NodeName  = lvl2.n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') 
                              ,NodeValue = lvl2.n.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
                         From  Data.nodes('*')  lvl1(n)
                         Cross Apply lvl1.n.nodes('*') lvl2(n) 
                     ) B
       ) src
 Pivot (max(NodeValue) for NodeName in ([DeveloperName],[PublisherName],[Genre]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Without the Pivot**

[image]

Comment: What are these lvl1 and lvl2?

Comment: @Darnold14 that was a safety net just incase you had  multiple "level 1" nodes.   This is optional.  If not needed.  Click on "edited 3 hours ago" to see the original.

Comment: Cool, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @Darnold14 Happy to help.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you! But I was wondering, I have been fooling around with this, but do you know why any GUID valued columns would come up null with this implementation?

Comment: @Darnold14 Huh, I'll take a peek

Comment: No worries, I figured it out. Thanks though!